# getResourceAsStream() returning null when reading from file in different project

Tags: java, file, inputstream, classloader, getresource

File.txt exist in a different java project (lets say Project 1, present in local machine). 
I've another java project (let's say Project 2, also present in local machine) from where I want to read this file contents using **getResourceAsStream**.

However, only if the File.txt exist in the same folder as SomeClassName.java (i.e both exist in Project 2), then it initializes InputStream, else **returns null** (path not found).

```
String textFilePath = "/absolute/path/to/file.txt";
ClassLoader clTest = SomeClassName.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream isTest = clTest.getResourceAsStream(textFilePath);
```

I tried using **absolute path** of the file but it doesn't work.

textFilePath format-

```
/Users/userName/RepoName/Project1/src/main/resources/file.txt
```

I CAN NOT move the file.txt from Project1 to Project 2.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Note - When I write a method inside the SomeClassName.java (in Project 2) to read and write the contents of the file.txt (in Project 1), it works fine.

Example - If I call the method

```
readFile(textFilePath);
String textFilePath = "/absolute/path/to/file.txt";
```

readFile is defined as -

```
private static void readFile(String propFile) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(propFile); 
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
    String line = buf.readLine(); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    while(line != null) { 
        sb.append(line).append("\n"); 
        line = buf.readLine(); 
        } 
    String fileAsString = sb.toString(); 
    System.out.println("Contents : " + fileAsString);
}
```

It reads and prints the file contents just fine.

Comment: Resource names are not file names, you cannot specify an absolute path, it is always resolved against the classloader (searchpath). If you define a IDE dependency or add the other project to the classpath it will find the name (if the resource name is a absolute or relative package in that project)

Comment: Make sure the other project is on the classpath or use a File not a resource